# Returning 5 results in PHP MySQL search

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

I want to only display 5 results from my database with my PHP search script. How can I do this?

My PHP code is:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
   $query= mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['q']));
}

$searchSQL = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$query}%'";
$searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)){
    $results[] = "<div class='webresult'><div class='title'><a href='{$row['url']}'>{$row['title']}</a></div><div class='desc'>{$row['description']}</div><div class='url'>{$row['url']}</div></div>";
}

echo implode($results); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$database=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
    $query= mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['q']));
    $searchSQL = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$query}%' LIMIT 0,5";
    //                                                                .^.
    //                                        add a limit clause here. |
    $searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)){
        $results[] = "<div class='webresult'><div class='title'><a href='{$row['url']}'>{$row['title']}</a></div><div class='desc'>{$row['description']}</div><div class='url'>{$row['url']}</div></div>";
    }

    echo implode($results); 
}
?>
```

1. **Solution**: Add a `LIMIT` clause to your query, in order to limit the number of the returned results.
2. **Suggestion**: Place your database querying code inside the if clause, because this way you will avoid troubles of the `GLOBAL` variables kind.

Comment: Just to clarify. The change was to add `LIMIT 0, 5`. You can find more info about the limit selector here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

where you have `$searchSQL = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE`title`LIKE '%{$query}%'";` you can change this to using a LIMIT clause like so:

```
$searchSQL = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$query}%' LIMIT 5";
```

For more information on using a LIMIT clause try the following links:

[MySQL Reference guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE `title` LIKE '%{$query}%' LIMIT 0,5"
```

that should display 5 results.